# how to sort data inserted into linked list and assign null pointer before its free list pointer

Tags: vb.net, linked-list, record

i am not supposed to use object-oriented concept here.

> freelistpointer means pointer that points to node that is  empty just after other non-empty ones
>
> > here **4** is freelistpointer

```
     Dim nullPointer As Integer = -1

    'nullpointer should be set to -1 if using array element with index 0
    Public Structure ListNode
        Public Data As Integer
        Public Pointer As Integer
    End Structure
    'declare record type to store data and pointer


    Dim StartPointer As Integer
    Dim FreeListPtr As Integer
    Dim List(6) As ListNode
    Dim newItem As Integer
    Dim NewNodePtr As Integer
    Dim ThisNodePtr As Integer
    Dim previousNodePtr As Integer
```

```
Sub InitialiseList()
        StartPointer = nullPointer 'set start pointer
        FreeListPtr = 1            'set starting position of free list
        For index As Integer = 0 To 5 'link all nodes to make free list
            List(index).Pointer = index + 1
        Next

        List(6).Pointer = nullPointer 'last node of free list    
    End Sub
```

```
Sub InsertNode(ByVal newItem)
        StartPointer = 0
        If FreeListPtr <> nullPointer Then 'there is space in the array
            'take node from free list and store data item
            NewNodePtr = FreeListPtr
            List(NewNodePtr).Data = newItem
            FreeListPtr = List(FreeListPtr).Pointer 'find insertion point
            ThisNodePtr = StartPointer 'start at beginning of list

            While ThisNodePtr <> nullPointer And List(ThisNodePtr).Data < newItem
                'while not end ofl list
                previousNodePtr = ThisNodePtr 'remember this node follow the pointer to the next node
                ThisNodePtr = List(ThisNodePtr).Pointer
            End While


           ' If previousNodePtr = StartPointer Then 'insert new node at start of list
            '    List(NewNodePtr).Pointer = StartPointer
            '    StartPointer = NewNodePtr
            'Else 'insert new node between previous node and this node
             '   List(NewNodePtr).Pointer = List(previousNodePtr).Pointer
             '   List(previousNodePtr).Pointer = NewNodePtr
            'End If

        End If
    End Sub
```

```
Sub OutputAllNodes()
        StartPointer = 0
        currentnodeptr = StartPointer
        For Each item In List
            Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("data", item.Data, " pointer", item.Pointer))
            'Console.WriteLine($"Data {item.Data}, Pointer {item.Pointer}")
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
```

```
Sub Main()
        InitialiseList()
        InsertNode(8)
        InsertNode(6)
        InsertNode(5)
        OutputAllNodes()
    End Sub
```

due to the commented out code in `insertNode()`, i can get following **output**

```
data8 pointer1
data6 pointer2
data5 pointer3
data0 pointer4
data0 pointer5
data0 pointer6
data0 pointer-1
```

however the commented out code is **expected** to get the following
**output**

```
data5 pointer1
data6 pointer2
data8 pointer-1
data0 pointer4
data0 pointer5
data0 pointer6
data0 pointer-1
```

***output*** without commenting at all

```
data8 pointer0
data6 pointer0
data5 pointer0
data0 pointer4
data0 pointer5
data0 pointer6
data0 pointer-1
```

i am unable to figure out where should i make amendments

**EDIT**

i have been able to assign null pointer before free list pointer without sorting i.e.

```
data8 pointer1
data6 pointer2
data5 pointer-1
data0 pointer4
data0 pointer5
data0 pointer6
data0 pointer-1
```

using following `insertnode()` function with `startpointer=nullpointer` in `initialiseList()` *commented* out

```
 Dim StartPointer As Integer = 0
 Dim previousNodePtr As Integer = 0
  Sub InsertNode(ByVal newItem)

        If FreeListPtr <> nullPointer Then 'there is space in the array
            'take node from free list and store data item
            NewNodePtr = FreeListPtr '0 because first element starts from 0 of the array
            List(NewNodePtr).Data = newItem '1:8, 2:6, 3:5
            FreeListPtr = List(FreeListPtr).Pointer 'find insertion point
            'ThisNodePtr = StartPointer 'start at beginning of list
            'data is inserted then pointer needs to be updated

            'startpointer is 1 and  
            If FreeListPtr = 0 Then 'insert new node at start of list
                List(NewNodePtr).Pointer = -1
                StartPointer = NewNodePtr
            Else 'insert new node between previous node and this node
                List(NewNodePtr).Pointer = -1
                List(previousNodePtr).Pointer = NewNodePtr

            End If
            previousNodePtr = NewNodePtr
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

See if we are getting any closer.

```
Module Module1

    Public Class ListNode
        Public Data As Integer
        Public Pointer As Integer
        Public Sub New(p As Integer)
            Pointer = p
        End Sub
    End Class

    Private InputList As New List(Of Integer)
    Private MySortedLinkedList As New List(Of ListNode)

    Sub Main()
        InitialiseList()
        InputList.Add(10)
        InputList.Add(8)
        InputList.Add(6)
        InputList.Add(4)
        InputList.Add(5)
        InputList.Add(9)
        AddDataToList(InputList)
        OutputAllNodes()
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddDataToList(lst As List(Of Integer))
        lst.Sort()
        Dim index As Integer
        For Each item In lst
            MySortedLinkedList(index).Data = item
            index += 1
        Next
    End Sub

    Sub InitialiseList()
        For index As Integer = 0 To 5 'link all nodes to make free list
            MySortedLinkedList.Add(New ListNode(index + 1))
        Next
        MySortedLinkedList.Add(New ListNode(-1)) 'last node of free list    
    End Sub

    Sub OutputAllNodes()
        For Each item In MySortedLinkedList
            Console.WriteLine($"Data {item.Data}, Pointer {item.Pointer}")
            'or in pre Visual Studio 2015
            'Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Data {0}, Pointer {1}", item.Data, item.Pointer)
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: pointer before freelistptr has to be -1 and u arent supposed to use builtin functions and object oriented approach

Comment: this is for high school students. its a question i have not been able to solve perfectly as required by syllabus. i think u got offended. sorry!

Comment: No, I am just mad at myself for being unable to help. Sorry.